# Android Studio Signed APK: Error SystemDependentName Must Not Be Null

Tags: android, android-studio

My apologies, I am quite new to app development! After downloading an open source Android Project, and importing it into Android Studio version 1.0.2, with JRE 1.7.0_75 on a W7 64 bit machine.

I get the following error when attempting to build the signed apk:

```
Error: Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of com/intellij/openapi/util/io/FileUtil.toSystemDependentName must not be null"
```

After much research, I cannot find anything referencing the above. I'm not quite sure where to proceed as I cant seem to find anything out of place or not configured properly in the project or Android Studio. The project builds fine, and I can generate an unsigned apk without issue. The problem only resides in trying to make a signed apk.

Thanks again for any input, I appreciate it!

Comment: Can we see your build.gradle files, please?

Comment: @ScottBarta sure! Once I figure out how to do that, I will post them!

Comment: @ScottBarta I think I found the answer, posted below. I used hyphens in the key file instead of spaces.

Comment: @JohnSpartan have you got answer ? have same question. when i update classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1 to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this error has to do with the name of the key I made when generating a signed apk. I decided to try it all again (without changing any of the code anywhere) and go for the build a signed apk wizard.

What I did differently: used hyphens instead of spaces in all the fields.

Magically, a signed, production ready apk was generated!